# How to have layer textures on a mesh in Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I am currently making a rig of a human, and the human face is divided into different textures so skin, eyes and eyebrows can be coloured. I have tried to duplicate the material for the face, since there is only one material, but all the textures use same mapping, but a texture never shows up, even after I rearrange it. I then tried using the node editor, which I am a noob at, but I cannot colour the textures without them colouring the other one, and I can only use 2, but I might be able to use more, I am still new to node editing. Is there any way I can do this in Cycles and be able to change their colour in Blender? Also this works in Blender Render, but I am not sure how to color there and keep the shading. If someone can fix this instead, it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: first decide whether you want to use cycles or BI. it can be done in either renderer.

Comment: Ok, I choose BI